# How to update the duplicate object in json array with a boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I got a small issue with an array. I want to identify the duplicate object in the array by updating the object attribute with boolean. Please see the below array.

```js
var jsonArray = [{
  SKILL: "Java",
  name: "ravi",
  checkDuplicate: ""
}, {
  SKILL: "SAP",
  name: "robert",
  checkDuplicate: ""
}, {
  SKILL: "Java",
  name: "rahim",
  checkDuplicate: ""
}, {
  SKILL: "Oracle",
  name: "singh",
  checkDuplicate: ""
}]
```

If you see the above array, `SKILL: Java` got duplicated. I want to update the array to the below format.

```js
var jsonArray = [{
  SKILL: "Java",
  name: "ravi",
  checkDuplicate: true
}, {
  SKILL: "SAP",
  name: "robert",
  checkDuplicate: false
}, {
  SKILL: "Java",
  name: "rahim",
  checkDuplicate: false
}, {
  SKILL: "Oracle",
  name: "singh",
  checkDuplicate: false
}]
```

Can someone please help me to get that requirement?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5TRqF/1/ you have to modify this

Comment: shouldn't be the 3rd element marked as "duplicated" as well…?

Comment: @ZER0, yeah. Even if three skills are duplicated, Only for one SKILL we need to have true and other 2 skills must be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jsonArray.map((item, i) => ({
    ...item,
    checkDuplicate: jsonArray.filter((o, j) => j>i).filter(o => o.SKILL == item.SKILL).length>0
}))
```

Output:

```
[
   {"SKILL":"Java","name":"ravi","checkDuplicate":true},
   {"SKILL":"SAP","name":"robert","checkDuplicate":false},
   {"SKILL":"Java","name":"rahim","checkDuplicate":false},
   {"SKILL":"Oracle","name":"singh","checkDuplicate":false}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonArray.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    checkDuplicate: jsonArray.filter(jsonArrayItem => jsonArrayItem.SKILL == item.SKILL).length>1
}))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "SKILL": "Java",
    "name": "ravi",
    "checkDuplicate": true
  },
  {
    "SKILL": "SAP",
    "name": "robert",
    "checkDuplicate": false
  },
  {
    "SKILL": "Java",
    "name": "rahim",
    "checkDuplicate": true
  },
  {
    "SKILL": "Oracle",
    "name": "singh",
    "checkDuplicate": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Here both Java object got updated to true, I dont want like that.. only for one object that must update to true and other it should be false.

Comment: Okay but then what about if there are three skill with the same value? Still only the first encountered should be set to `true` and the other two to `false`?

Comment: Please check my other answer, now it's ok, I just added a filter() to check if the current element exists in the next elements

Comment: @ZER0, yeah. Even if three skills are duplicated, Only for one SKILL we need to have true and other 2 skills must be false.

Comment: Ok then you can use my other answer and replace "length>0" with "length==1" and only one will be true (the one before the last)

Answer (score 0):

So based on the comments, something like that should works:

```
var jsonArray = [{
  SKILL: "Java",
  name: "ravi",
  checkDuplicate: ""
}, {
  SKILL: "SAP",
  name: "robert",
  checkDuplicate: ""
}, {
  SKILL: "Java",
  name: "rahim",
  checkDuplicate: ""
}, {
  SKILL: "Oracle",
  name: "singh",
  checkDuplicate: ""
}]

// We need an helper function that works similar to both 
// array's `find`:
// <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find>
//
// and `indexOf`:
// <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf>
//
const find = (array, predicate, fromIndex) => {
    for (let i = fromIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (predicate(array[i], i)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Here the main loop, we also declare a `dupes` object to keep
// track of the duplicated `SKILL`
for (let dupes = {}, i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
  let {SKILL} = jsonArray[i];

  // increment using negate + NOT
  dupes[SKILL] = -~dupes[SKILL]; 

  // Here we mutate the array, and we set `true`
  // only if it's the first time we encounter this `SKILL`
  // and if there are items with the same `SKILL` after
  // the current item
  jsonArray[i].checkDuplicate = dupes[SKILL] === 1 && find(jsonArray, item => item.SKILL === SKILL, i + 1);
}

jsonArray
```